# Using PHP (Windows) how to create a variable directory (containing date) when referring to a new path?

Tags: php

So far what I was able to obtain the following directory when running this code:
A:\TEST\WQER/TECH/2014 when I echo the created path. Unfortunately the program does not create the directory TECH/2014 but instead creates a the directory "$dir" in the users directory. You will notice that the frontslash (Unix) is used instead of the backslash (Windows) when we echo the result.

```
<?php

   $Year = 'TECH' . '/'. date('Y') . '/'; 
   $dir = 'A:\TEST\WQER' . '/'. $Year . "\n";
   echo 'directory =' . $dir . "\n";

   exec('mkdir $dir .'/'.');

 ?>
```

Comment: YOu can use `/` in windows too. And any way, why don't you use the php built in `mkdir` function?

Answer (score 1):

Basic PHP syntax: `'`-quote strings do **NOT** interpolate variables:

```
   exec('mkdir $dir .'/'.');
        ^------------^
```

With the quotes set as you have, you're literally doing:

```
exec(string divided by string)
```

which will simply cause a divide-by-zero error when PHP converts those strigs to ints.

You want

```
exec("mkdir $dir");
```

instead. You can't mkdir a `.` dir anyways. It's automatically present in ALL directories, and you can't create or remove it.